# Responsive menu bug

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive menu like the Bootstrap nav bar using just CSS.
I have got actual function working, however the positioning of the menu grabber is wrong and I'm not quite sure how to fix it.. the grabber should be inline with the logo text and the red box should only appear (with items below the black bar)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="clearfix">
        <span class="logo">Logo</span>

        <input type="checkbox" id="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-checkbox">
        <nav class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="history.php">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="reviews.php">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu-toggle">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="location.php">Location</a></li>
            </ul>
        <label for="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-handle"></label>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .nav-menu {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
.nav-menu {
    padding: 0.5em;
    /*background: #eee;*/
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    min-height: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.nav-menu ul {
    transition: max-height 0.25s linear;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.nav-menu li {
    transition: visibility .25s linear;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 .75em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.nav-menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: .70em 1em;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #ffed8b;
    color: #000;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .nav-menu ul {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 3.5em 0 1em;
    }
    .nav-menu li {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
    }
    .nav-menu .navbar-handle {
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu ul {
        max-height: 300px;
    }
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu li {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu .navbar-handle,
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu .navbar-handle:after,
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu .navbar-handle:before {
        border-color: #aaa;
    }
}
.navbar-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.navbar-handle {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding: .5em 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 1.6em;
    border-top: 0.1em solid;
}
.navbar-handle:before,
.navbar-handle:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: ' ';
    border-top: 0.1em solid;
}
.navbar-handle:before {
    top: 0.3em;
}
.navbar-handle:after {
    top: 0.8em;
}
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.menu .navbar-handle {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    top: 0.7em;
    right: 12px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ykvfE)**

Comment: images/logo-header.png doesn't seem to exist on your CodePen example.

Comment: @AndrewMorton you are correct, but it doesn't make a difference to the layout or the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the " -toggle" in your CSS you have ".menu" it should look like **".menu-toggle"**: here is some mark-up to get you started:

```css
/* Your can adjust the CSS however you see fit for your Project */
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .nav-menu {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}
.nav-menu {
    padding: 0.5em;
    /*background: #eee;*/
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    min-height: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.nav-menu ul {
    transition: max-height 0.25s linear;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.nav-menu li {
    transition: visibility .25s linear;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 .75em;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.nav-menu li a {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: .70em 1em;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover {
    display: block;
    background: #ffed8b;
    color: #000;
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .nav-menu ul {
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 3.5em 0 1em;
    }
    .nav-menu li {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
    }
    .nav-menu .navbar-handle {
        display: block;
        float: right;
    }
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu ul {
        max-height: 300px;
    }
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu li {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu .navbar-handle,
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu .navbar-handle:after,
    #navbar-checkbox:checked + .nav-menu .navbar-handle:before {
        border-color: #aaa;
    }
}
.navbar-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.navbar-handle {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding: .5em 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 1.6em;
    border-top: 0.1em solid;
}
.navbar-handle:before,
.navbar-handle:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    content: ' ';
    border-top: 0.1em solid;
}
.navbar-handle:before {
    top: 0.3em;
}
.navbar-handle:after {
    top: 0.8em;
}
.menu-toggle { /* Correction Needed To Be Made Here Now You Can Make Adjustments */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30;
 
 
}
.menu .navbar-handle {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    top: 0.7em;
    right: 12px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="clearfix">
        <span class="logo">Logo</span>

        <input type="checkbox" id="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-checkbox">
        <nav class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="history.php">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="reviews.php">Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu-toggle">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="location.php">Location</a></li>
            </ul>
        <label for="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-handle"></label>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The menu grabber still appear below the menu links and appears below them when expanded. This is not the desired function, the only different I see in your example is that there is now an additional 'menu' button which I'm not sure what it does as it doesnt expand or collapse.

Comment: its not an additional button I was merely pointing out that you have a class="menu-toggle" that was not shown in your css so this function needed to be corrected in your css in order for you to get the result. Read my text inside the code up top.

Comment: Did you mean to put "<li><a href="#" class="menu-toggle">menu</a><li>"? If so then where in your CSS is it defined?